# Basic Stringify question with call back function

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

So I just started learning json and have a question.

```
const rabbit = {
  name: 'BobJ',
  color: 'black',
  size: null,
  birthDate: new Date(),
  jump: () => {
    console.log(`${name} can jump!`);
  }
}

json = JSON.stringify(rabbit, (key, value) => {
  console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${value}`);
  return key === 'name' ? 'Elsa' : value;
});
console.log(json)
```

this `*return key === 'name' ? 'Ellie' : value;*` part means if there is a 'name' key, set the value to Ellie, else return its original value.

What if I wanted to have **more then 2 keys** in that code? like *name* and *color*? how would the code look like?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your desired output?  Do you want to produce { `name: "Elsa", color: "black" }`?

Answer (score 1):

You could put multiple [if else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) condition.

```js
if (key === 'name') {
 return 'Elsa'
} else if (key === 'color') {
  return 'Green'
} 
// if nothing else
return value
```

You could also use a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement. Or a [nested ternary](https://jonathanleemartin.com/tldr/01-nested-ternaries/).

I like to use a hashmap/object for this.

```js
const rabbit = {
  name: 'BobJ',
  color: 'black',
  size: null,
  birthDate: new Date(),
  jump: () => {
    console.log(`${name} can jump!`);
  }
}

const keyMap = {
  name: "Elsa",
  color: "Green",
}

json = JSON.stringify(rabbit, (key, value) => {
  console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${value}`);
  return keyMap[key] || value
});

console.log(json)
```